# Ionic 3 ion-option selected items not deselect after reload or re-initialized array?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic3

Html file:

```
<ion-item class="inputpsection" *ngIf="showDeptsec">
          <ion-label floating class="fontsize12">Department</ion-label>
          <ion-select (ionChange)="showDepartmentChosen($event)" multiple="true" formControlName="depId"
            [(ngModel)]="depItems">
            <ion-option value="{{dept.id}}" *ngFor="let dept of deptAPIdata" [selected]="dept.selected">{{dept.name}}
            </ion-option>
          </ion-select>
        </ion-item>
        <!-- SUB-DEPARTMENT -->
        <ion-item class="inputpsection" *ngIf="showSubDeptsec">
          <ion-label floating class="fontsize12">Sub-Department</ion-label>
          <ion-select (ionChange)="showSubDeptChosen($event)" multiple="true" formControlName="subdepId"
            [(ngModel)]="subDepItems">
            <ion-option value="{{subDept.id}}" *ngFor="let subDept of subdeptAPIdata" [selected]="subDept.selected">
              {{subDept.name}}</ion-option>
          </ion-select>
        </ion-item>
```

ts file:

```
export class DashboardPage {
public deptAPIdata: any = [];
public subdeptAPIdata: any = [];

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,public remoteData: RemoteDataProvider){

}
showDepartmentChosen(itemVal: any): void {
      this.getDepartment_dropdownItems()
 }
getDepartment_unit_dropdownItems() {
    this.remoteData.callAPIforDepUnit()
      .then(data => {
        this.apiData = JSON.stringify(data);
        let obj: dep_unit = JSON.parse(this.apiData);
        if (obj.status === 1) {
          this.subdeptAPIdata = obj.subdeptData;

          //for deselecting items
          if (this.subDepItems.length > 0) {
          for (var i = 0; i < this.subdeptAPIdata.length; i++) {
            this.subDepItems.forEach((element: string) => {
              if (element == this.subdeptAPIdata[i]['id']) {
                this.subdeptAPIdata[i]['selected'] = false;

                 }
            });
          }
        }
        }
      });
  }
}
```

All options values both for department and sub-department displaying dynamically from API when the page load initially. and when i choose any items(it can be multiple items) of department option and after then just called another api to fetch sub-department data according to the department ids and re-initialized `this.subdeptAPIdata` array data.
But the problem is that sub-department data can't be deselect which one was previously selected.I just want to refresh the array and reload the data again for sub-department without checked any itmes.

Please let me know if you guys have any strong solutions or i did any mistakes on code...Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: It would be easier to help if you could create a StackBlitz example of the same with sample data.

Answer (score 0):

subDepItems becomes an array for multiple select. set this to empty array before reloading your data to reset the select box.

> this.subDepItems = [];